# Default Common FJThread pool vs custom FJ Pool

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-9, forkjoinpool

I have an I/O operation which is to be made multithreaded. Its a recursive algorithm where a task spawns more of the subtasks in recursion. I read that FJ pool can be used for recursive tasks, so thereby tried 2 things that uses FJ Pool.

> 1 Parallel streams which uses default common FJpool -> I observed that in this case the thread off-loaded its task to run its subtask. So lets say there is a  worker-thread1 from FJCommonPool and I see that it off-loaded its task and ran all the subtasks spawn in a recursive process.
>
> 2 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Some-function,Custom-FJPool) -> I observed here that if I submit this task to Custom-FJPool, the thread did not off-loaded its task to run its subtask but it was observed that every subtask was assigned to a new thread from the custom pool. As its recursion and once the Custom-FJPool is out of threads, it tries to compensate by adding more threads, so the active count of threads increases but no of running threads is still less or equal to parallelism level of Custom-FJPool. I thought even with Custom-FJPool a thread should have off-loaded its task to run its subtask, but that did not happen.

Can anyone share some insights why Custom-FJPool threads behavior is different from Common-FJPool and why offloading of tasks doesn't happen with custom FJ pool.

#### Example

Lets consider a tree structure but for simplicity lets assume every parent has a single child (`LinkedList` structure). So it can be something like `ParentDir/d1/d2/d3/d4/d5/d6/d7/d8/d9`. Now if I want to delete `ParentDir`, the algorithm would be something like find the leaf node recursively and once found, start deleting till we delete `ParentDir`. If this algorithm is thrown to a parallel streams which uses commonForkJoinPool its seen that only 1 thread from the commonFJPool would do the whole task. It offloads the tasks and start working on subtasks(deleting children) and so on till `ParentDir` is deleted.

But if this same algorithm is performed using parallel streams using custom FJPool then its seen as Thread T1 is assigned the task to delete `ParentDir`, Thread T2 to delete children `d1`, Thread T3 to children `d3` and T4 to `d4` and so on. So here is no offloading of the tasks takes place as seen with commonFJPool. I am curious why this happens?

Comment: You are comparing the behavior of parallel streams and `CompletableFuture`, not the common pool vs custom pool. Different program code, different behavior. The pool implementation code doesn’t change.

Comment: Ok but isn't ComputableFuture non blocking by nature, so I am just wondering why did the threads got blocked on a task and did not offload it task and executed the subtasks.

Comment: BTW I am seeing the same behavior with parallel streams when submit to a custom ForkJoinPool. Can we consider this as comparing common pool to custom pool?

Comment: Right, `ComputableFuture` is non blocking by nature, so if you see blocked tasks, it must be *your* tasks, which block, which is not too far-fetched, as you are doing I/O, further, you are doing task decomposition, which likely implies waiting for partial results, hence blocking. The parallel stream must wait for partial results in principle, so it must block. In the best case, it’s very short, when all sub tasks complete at the same time, but using a custom pool is not an ideal case, as it is not even a planned feature. The implementation still uses artifacts of the default pool in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Holger. I got it,  but how do parallel streams (using default common pool) offload the task and performs subtasks.

Comment: You have a strange way of using the term “offloading”. Normally, people would associate that term with the execution by a different thread, as executing code by the same thread is the norm, which happens for every ordinary method invocation.  Besides that, you should show the actual code for your example, which exhibits the described behavior.